# Automatic drag and drop utility on osx

Tags: macos, drag-and-drop, keyboard-shortcuts

I often take screenshots (<kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>maj</kbd> + <kbd>4</kbd>) that are saved on my desktop. I then drag and drop them where I want to publish them (Messenger app, or Facebook status, E-mail, etc.).

My app are often fullscreen so it's a pain to perform the drag and drop.

Is there any tool that would let me perform the drag and drop with keyboard shortcuts similar to how we copy/past using <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd> and <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd>?

For instance, go on the desktop, select the image, <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>key</kbd> then go to email and <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>second_key</kbd> to auto-drag-and-drop.

Otherwise, how would I start to build it myself ? Or any ideas as to how I should proceed to achieve similar result ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Note: I still haven't found a good way to automate the drag and drop, but I found Yoink.app on the app store. It avoids me a lot of pain when doing the drag and drop because you don't have to resize your windows. Sadly, it's a paid app.

> When you start dragging files in Finder or content from an
>   application, Yoink fades in a tiny window at the edge of your screen
>   so you can drag to it.This frees up your mouse so you can comfortably
>   navigate to the destination of the files and resume the drag from
>   Yoink's window more comfortably.

You can download it here: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/yoink-improved-drag-drop-file-management/id457622435?mt=12

Answer (score 1):

With Keyboard Maestro utility software you can set up one macro to handle the workflow from start to finish:

1. screen shot
2. dialog asking you where to send/publish (Messenger, Facebook, etc.)
3. copy-paste OR open-with to send to the destination specified

There are other shortcut macro utilities, but Keyboard Maestro is the one I use so it's what I know.

Comment: sadly my app (telegram.app) doesn't accept pasting imgs or open with